# How to repopulate WTForms

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, wtforms

so i have made a form in WTForms with an edit button which allows the user to edit the previous data in the form.

The problem i have is fetching the new data from the form.when i do request.form i get the following:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('location_name', u'b'), ('feed_url', u'bkj'), ('title', u'b'), ('url', u'b'), ('date_crawled', u'b'), ('content_url', u'b'), ('longitude', u'b'), ('latitude', u'b'), ('date_added', u'b'), ('types', u'b')])
```

what i want is to retrieve the following from the above output

```
('location_name', u'b'), ('feed_url', u'bkj'), ('title', u'b'), ('url', u'b'), ('date_crawled', u'b'), ('content_url', u'b'), ('longitude', u'b'), ('latitude', u'b'), ('date_added', u'b'), ('types', u'b')])
```

Answer (score 1):

You already did the work of writing out a form class in WTForms (and I suspect Flask-WTF, given that the crsf_token would not be there normally unless you're using CSRF on purpose).

so that means you already did something akin to:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    feed_url = TextField(...)
    # etc
```

and then you already did something like

```
def my_view():
    form = MyForm(request.form)
    render('mytemplate.html', form=form)
```

Now that you have this awesome form object, use it!  That is, access the data off either `form.data` or `form.feed_url.data` which contains datatype-coerced data. Furthermore, you can use the validation logic in wtforms to make sure you don't have any bad data.  There's no reason to use `request.form` which is the raw input coming from your framework.

This will land you with something like (note this is a generic example for an imaginary pseudo-framework, you will need to get the appropriate call names for your framework):

```
def edit_location(location_id):
    my_object = LocationInfo.get(location_id)
    form = MyForm(request.form, obj=my_object)
    if request.form and form.validate():
        # If we got here, we have POST data and the form validated.
        form.populate_obj(my_object) # Super cool magic!
        my_object.save()
        return redirect(...)

    # If we fall back to here, it means validation failed or we're
    # viewing the form for the first time.
    render('mytemplate.html', form=form)
```

I recommend you read the [Crash Course](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/dev/crash_course.html) for WTForms and also some of the other docs on there for a better idea of how to use WTForms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to filter out the csrf_tokens.

```
>>> import werkzeug
>>> i = werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict([('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('location_name', u'b'), ('feed_url', u'bkj'), ('title', u'b'), ('url', u'b'), ('date_crawled', u'b'), ('content_url', u'b'), ('longitude', u'b'), ('latitude', u'b'), ('date_added', u'b'), ('types', u'b')])
>>> i
ImmutableMultiDict([('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('csrf_token', u'20130702225444##3f1c28cecaf55dc0e441d9820dfb52bb6df3d200'), ('location_name', u'b'), ('feed_url', u'bkj'), ('title', u'b'), ('url', u'b'), ('date_crawled', u'b'), ('content_url', u'b'), ('longitude', u'b'), ('latitude', u'b'), ('date_added', u'b'), ('types', u'b')])
>>> keys = ['location_name', 'feed_url', 'title', 'url', 'date_crawled', 'content_url', 'longitude', 'latitude', 'date_added', 'types']
>>> data = [(key, i[key]) for key in i if key in keys]
>>> data
[('location_name', u'b'), ('feed_url', u'bkj'), ('title', u'b'), ('url', u'b'), ('date_crawled', u'b'), ('content_url', u'b'), ('longitude', u'b'), ('latitude', u'b'), ('date_added', u'b'), ('types', u'b')]
>>>
```