# How to get variable from a list field

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

Hi i have a variable that prints out the following:

```
data=[('location_name', u'b'), ('feed_url', u'bkj'), ('title', u'b'), ('url', u'b')]
```

I am using python i was wondering how to i extract the content of location_name for example from this list, i have tried doing the following:

```
data[0]// this prints out ('location_name', u'b')
```

What i want is to get the content of location_name so in this case i get b

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
data=[('location_name', u'b'), ('feed_url', u'bkj'), ('title', u'b'), ('url', u'b')]
d = dict(data)

print d["location_name"]
```

Comment: However it's not worthwhile creating the dict in the case you only need to do one lookup

Comment: @gnibbler he already has it in dict form, he just wont use it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436156/how-to-repopulate-wtforms

Comment: @gnibbler, also I just missed the daily rep cap by an upvote, <sad face>

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of tuples.  Therefore, to print that value you would want simply to do:

```
print data[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acess a data using index.
Like
`test=[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7)]`

```
teste[0] # will access the first element that is (1, 2, 3)
'(1, 2, 3)'
teste[0][0] # will access the element (1, 2, 3) then the second index [0] will access 1
'1'
```

As inner as the element is, more index you will need.